# Smack Exception - caused by my Java installation or by Smack

Tags: java, exception, xmpp, smack

I'm using Smack API to develop a multi-user gaming client. 
I've got a problem with my smack application: i can send messages and requests to the server, but my application can't read responses from it.

```
Exception in thread "Smack Packet Reader (0)" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
          at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
          at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
          at org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.ProviderManager.initialize(ProviderManager.java :193)
          at org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.ProviderManager.<init>(ProviderManager.java:436 )
          at org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.ProviderManager.getInstance(ProviderManager.jav a:134)
          at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.PacketParserUtils.parseIQ(PacketParserUtils.java:30 3)
          at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:229)
          at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:43)
          at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
          at java.util.TimeZone.parseCustomTimeZone(TimeZone.java:767)
          at java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.java:471)
          at java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.java:465)
          at org.jivesoftware.smackx.workgroup.packet.TranscriptsProvider.<clinit>(Transcrip tsProvider.java:44)
          ... 9 more
No response from the server.:
```

It's not a network (firewall, nat...) problem (on another Macintosh in the same subnet, the same code runs well with no exceptions). I checked my MacOS firewall and it seems ok...what can I do to resolve this issue?
I don't know if this issue depends on java or Smack...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be passing a `null` to `parseCustomTimeZone`?

Comment: No problem. I haven't used Smack, but I often see these exceptions from the Java library due to methods assuming non-null parameters are passed in. Easiest way to test is try to directly invoke it with `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is not possible, because I don't use this method...maybe Smack is using this method somewhere in the API, but this is a strange issue because the same code runs well on another computer.

Comment: Are you saying that you can't try `class MyTest{public static void main(String[] args){java.util.TimeZone.parseCustomTimeZone(null);}}`? I can't because I'm not using Java 7.

Comment: Oh, sorry...I didn't understand your request! Tomorrow morning (here in Italy is late right now :) ) I'll try to use that method and I'll post here the result. Anyway, I'm using java 1.6.0_24

Comment: Tried it myself. First of all, I was wrong about it being Java 7. `parseCustomTimeZone` is private. I called `getTimeZone` with `null` and got a `NullPointerException`, but a different stack trace.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! So, in your opinion, what does it mean? Is my problem due to my Java installation or something else?

Comment: Inconclusive! See that answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This more of a continuation of the comments rather than a *complete* answer (but hopefully it helps).

The offending line in the java source reads `zi.setID("GMT+00:00");`. zi is of type `sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo`. This can only mean that zi is `null`. Further up it is being created as follows:

```
zi = ZoneInfoFile.getZoneInfo("GMT");
```

So I wrote the following little test program:

```
class Foobar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo zi = sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.getZoneInfo("GMT");
        zi.setID("GMT+00:00:00");
    }
}
```

I didn't get any `NullPointerException` or any other type of exception. Perhaps you could run the same test program and see what happens. My guess is that it will fail for you. It might indicate a borked Java installation.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I get a NullPointerException on         zi.setID("GMT+00:00:00");

Comment: Did you trace it back to the root cause? Obviously something in smack is passing dodgy data to the method.

Comment: The root cause is, as supposed by you, my java installation. I installed the last update released by Apple 5 days ago (1.6_026) and now my code works fine! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem. I figured that much as soon as I saw null being returned when zone info was requested from the zone file.

Comment: @Steve - Smack is passing "GMT+0", which is not dodgy, although the +0 is probably redundant.